# get 2D array from text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the 2D array from the text file. So far I accessed the file and got all the numbers in the file, but all these numbers are string so I used **split()** and then convert it to double. How can convert this to double 2D array?

1.65 4.50 2.36 7.45 3.44 6.23

2.22 -3.24 -1.66 -5.48 3.46

4.23 2.29 5.29

2.76 3.76 4.29 5.48 3.43

3.38 3.65 3.76

2.46 3.34 2.38 8.26 5.34

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws FileNotFoundException {

     File file =  new File("district3.txt");

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(file); 
     String b; 
     String[] c;

     int r = 6;

     double[][]arr = new double[r][];


     while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        //get number as String
        b = scan.nextLine();

        //split them 
         c = b.split(" ");

         for(String i:c)
            System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(i) );




     } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `for` to `print` inline and then add a `println` after you've printed all the numbers:

```
for(String i:c)
            System.out.print(i + " ");

System.out.println()
```

To store the numbers you can do the following:

```
double[][]arr = new double[r][];

int i = 0;
while(scan.hasNextLine()) {

    //get number as String
    b = scan.nextLine();

    //split them 
    c = b.split(" ");
    arr[i] = new double[c.length];
    for(int j = 0; j < c.length; ++j) {
        arr[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(c[j]);
        // Display them if needed
        System.out.print(c[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    ++i;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, actually i want to store these number as 2D array